# LPC1768 Programming in keil

Tags: arm, keil, lpc

I have a problem with keil
i write a simple peace of code used to turn ON and OFF All GPIO2 in LPC1768 but it return 110 Warning!

Here is my Code:

```
#include <LPC17xx.h>   


void delay_ms(unsigned int ms);
void delay_ms(unsigned int ms)
{
    unsigned int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<ms;i++)
        for(j=0;j<20000;j++);
}

/* start the main program */
int main() 
{
    SystemInit();                    //Clock and PLL configuration 
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 = 0x000000;  //Configure the PORT2 Pins as GPIO;
    LPC_GPIO2->FIODIR = 0xffffffff;  //Configure the PORT2 pins as OUTPUT;

    while(1)
    {
        LPC_GPIO2->FIOSET = 0xffffffff;     // Make all the Port pins as high  
        delay_ms(100);

        LPC_GPIO2->FIOCLR = 0xffffffff;     // Make all the Port pins as low  
        delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

And Here is my results:
[[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRcFl.png)]
[[WARNINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvxuA.png)]

I tried reinstall all software pack and keil but it doesn't help
and at first place keil returned "use of old-style cast" I fixed it Under Project -> Options For Target -> C/C++ tab , for Misc controls "-Wno-old-style-cast" press OK and rebuild the project.

Comment: so you are saying it does not build/compile or are you asking about other problems with your code (that once it compiles it still wont blink the led...as written).

Comment: it compiles and it works but why there is 110 warnings in "LPC17xx.h" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another compiler.

Under Options for Target you can select the compiler in the tab 'Target'. I always use compiler version 5 (you may have to install it), because version 6 always shows strange warnings in my experience.

Comment: thank you so much do you have Download link?